# Update post meta not firing on transition post status

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to add the woocommerce sale dates whenever a new product is published (draft to publish).

All my code works down to my comment and all the variables echo out fine with no errors, but when I check the post meta and the admin, no dates are added. Nothing in get_post_meta and nothing in the product edit screen.

```
add_action('transition_post_status', array($this, 'knp_add_sale_date'), 20, 3);
public function knp_add_sale_date($new, $old, $post){

    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
    $submissiondata = $this->get_submission($meta['submissionID'][0]);
    $submissiondata['live_status'] = $new;

    //If the post is a new product published from draft. 
    if ($old == 'draft' && $new == 'publish' && $post->post_type == 'product') {    

        //If there is a sale on then set the sale dates
        if (isset($meta['_sale_price'][0])) {   
            $startdatedate = new DateTime('now');
            $startdateformat = $startdatedate->format('Y-m-d');
            $enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startdateformat. ' + 15 days'));
            $finishdate = new DateTime($enddate);       

            //Everything works till here
            update_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price_dates_from', $startdatedate->getTimestamp());
            update_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price_dates_to', $finishdate->getTimestamp());

        }   
        $update = $this->post_submission($submissiondata, $meta['submissionID'][0], 'live');                                            

    }       

}
```

TIA for any suggestions or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intent to access only one meta you should pass the meta key to filter it out exact value.

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sale_price', true);
```

Also check the postmeta table for this post id if '_sale_price' is set or not when you change hook `'transition_post_status'` this action.

This hook applied before post_save to database and if meta not saved before you can't get the value from database if it's not being set.